# Setting an Exchange contact email address to null/String.Empty

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices

Using Exchange Web Services 2.0 (EWS) how do I set a Contact's email address to null or String.Empty without getting the error "An object within a change description must contain one and only one property to modify."?

```
// Causes error.
string emailAddress = String.Empty;
MyContact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = new EmailAddress(emailAddress);
```

If I set it to a '-' or a valid email address it works fine.

```
// No error.
string emailAddress = "-";
MyContact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = new EmailAddress(emailAddress);
```

So how do I clear an email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `EmailAddress` makes internal parsing of the string you gave in constructor:

```
new EmailAddress(emailAddress);
```

So you can not do it that way, passing string.Empty.

Check the forllowing link to remote email from contacts:

[EWS Managed API: How to remove Email1, Email2, Email3 from a contact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2012/05/17/ews-managed-api-how-to-remove-email1-email2-email3-from-a-contact.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Carlos, that did the trick.  I am not sure I understand why they couldn't have implemented:

    MyContact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = String.Empty;

or something similar.  But at least I have managed to get it to work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CarlClark I think they implemented it! I just used `myContact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = null;` and it worked! (office365 version)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the Email Value as following. You don't need a constructor

```
    string emailAddress = String.Empty;
    MyContact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = emailAddress;
```